# Join tables in sqlite with many to many

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have the following database schema:

```
create table people (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
);

create table groups (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
);
```

and I already have which people are members of which groups in a separate file (let's say in tuples of (`person id`, `group id`). How can I structure my database schema such that it's easy to access a person's groups, and also easy to access the members of a group? It is difficult and slow to read the tuples that I currently have, so I want this to be in database form. I can't have things like `member1`, `member2`, etc. as columns because the number of people in a group is currently unlimited.

Comment: Please post the query that you have tried.

Comment: Are the members of the groups in a file (.txt, .php, .csv, etc) or are they another table groups_people

Comment: @ChristopherIckes They are in a .txt file.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I don't really know where to start; I'm building this without any sql experience.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: If someone comes to you for a swimming lesson, do you ask him to show his failed attempts?

Comment: @Andomar If someone comes to a swimming pool for a swimming lesson I would point them to the sign that says "[FAQ:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) We expect you to have stepped in water before and tell us what type of water experiences you've had."

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Not sure if your reply is serious, but no, a swimming pool does not have a FAQ.  And if it had, nobody would read it.  Swimming trainers are friendly,  easy going, and they go out of their way to welcome new swimmers.

Comment: This ain't your friendly neighborhood swimming pool brah. This right here is an ivy league elite varsity swim meet. And unless you can butterfly under a 2:20 we're gonna kick your ass. You swimmin with the sharks son. We only help those who don't need it /s

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Move your text file into a database table

```
CREATE TABLE groups_people (
  groups_id integer,
  people_id integer,
  PRIMARY KEY(group_id, people_id)
);
```

And select all people that are a member of group 7

```
SELECT * FROM people p  
  LEFT JOIN groups_people gp ON gp.people_id = p.id  
  WHERE gp.groups_id = '7';
```

And select all the groups that person 5 is in

```
SELECT * FROM groups g  
  LEFT JOIN groups_people gp ON gp.groups_id = g.id  
  WHERE gp.people_id = '5';
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a very clear answer, and I like it a lot. I was planning on serializing the groups and memberships, which is a lot less elegant. One question: if I had a group with N members and many groups with one member, would this approach create N empty "membership spaces" for the groups that all had one member (assume N > 1)? Or is SQL smart enough to not do this?

Comment: @jclancy: No, you will have 1 row in the `groups_people` table for every group-member relationship. So, for the group with N members, there would be N rows in that table. For a group with 1 member, only 1 row. For a group without members, no rows at the table.

Comment: @jclancy Glad I could help.  If this has solved your problem, can you please mark the answer as accepted?  Thanks.