# Print values from another table SQLite3 w/ Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, foreign-keys

I want to create a simple recipe script. So I have a Table with some recipes and one with ingredients. Now I linked all `ingredients_id` to the the recipe.

Is it possible to print the name of those id's from another table?

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('food.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ingredients (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            name TEXT NOT NULL)""")

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipes (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
            name TEXT NOT NULL, 
            quantity REAL, 
            ingredients_id TEXT, 
            FOREIGN KEY(ingredients_id) REFERENCES ingredients(id)
            )""")


c.execute("INSERT INTO recipes VALUES ('0', 'Pasta with Tomato', '1', '2,3')")


c.execute("INSERT INTO ingredients VALUES ('2', 'Pasta')")

c.execute("INSERT INTO ingredients VALUES ('3', 'Tomato')")

c.execute("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE id='0'")

print(c.fetchone())

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is classic [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship.

Each product can be ingredient in many recipes, each recipe can have multiple ingredients.

To implement this, you need 3rd table, that holds "membership" per product per recipe. This is common (if not best) practice for m2m problem.

There's a lot of examples in SO, pls [look for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549971/join-tables-in-sqlite-with-many-to-many)

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps me. But is it possible to link two ingredient_id's to a recipe and print the names of those id's which are included in the recipe?

Comment: No way that I know with sql